# Culture with money SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This:

`SELECT 'R$ '+convert(varchar(50), CAST(998547 as money), -1) MONEYVALUE`

Will output: `R$ 998,547.00`

In Brazil the right is: `R$ 998.547,00`

How can I output the right format?

Comment: don't have the db do the formatting. have your db output `998547.00`, then do the formatting in your client-side code. the db should never have to worry about who's sitting at the keyboard and what their national format is.

Comment: Or if you absolutely must, you can write your own UDF that will use SQL string functions to convert the money datatype to the desired string format.

Comment: @Marc B, Ok you got me.

Comment: @Khrys - Though Marc B, makes a good point, I believe the correct answer to the question you asked was posted below by Andrew and probably should be marked as so.

Comment: @dcary, not because `FORMAT` isn't an option in sql-server-2008-r2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the currency format using a selected culture by parameter for SQL Server 2012.

Like this:

```
select
    'R$ ' + CONVERT(varchar(50), cast(MONEYVAL as MONEY), -1) MONEYVALUE -- Custom Format
    , FORMAT(MONEYVAL, 'C', 'en-us') USA
    , FORMAT(MONEYVAL, 'C', 'pt-br') Brazil
from ACCOUNT;
```

Look for currency format at the [official site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh213505.aspx)

You can see the example at the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8fc2/5)

For Sever 2008 R2 dosen't have a native function to format currency, but you could download some library like [this](http://www.sqlsharp.com/) or write your own format function or simple just use replace to make it easy but not so fency.

```
SELECT 
    'R$ ' + convert(varchar(50), CAST(moneyVal as money), -1) MONEYVALUE,
    'RS ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(50), (CAST(moneyVal AS money)), -1), ',', ';'), '.', ','), ';', '.')
from Account
```

Comment: `FORMAT` isn't avaiable in sql-server-2008-r2